# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem with Laragon and Laravel Broadcasting

Tags: laravel, curl, openssl, pusher

Trying to test a private channel for notifications through Pusher using the Laravel 8 framework on a local Laragon server I can't get to understand what causes this error.

I have the php.ini configured properly (I hope) for SSL and I can access the local https domain

```
;; php.ini
extension=openssl

curl.cainfo = "C:/laragon/etc/ssl/cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile = "C:/laragon/etc/ssl/ca-bundle.crt"
```

In the Laravel configuration file (*broadcasting.php*) I have this

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'useTLS' => true,
        ],
],
```

Public channels work when I send messages but private messages like the one used for notifications do not get across and I guess it's because of this error reported by the queue worker

```
[2021-05-05 09:09:49] local.ERROR: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://api-eu.pusher.com/apps[CODE REMOVED] {"exception":"[object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException(code: 0): 
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://api-eu.pusher.com/apps/[CODE REMOVED] at source\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php:211)
```

I also tried adding this to the configuration:

```
'options' => [
    ....
    'curl_options' => [
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    ]
],
```

but didn't do the trick, either. When I execute `openssl_get_cert_locations()`, I get this:

`{ ["default_cert_file"]=> string(42) "C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL/cert.pem" ["default_cert_file_env"]=> string(13) "SSL_CERT_FILE" ["default_cert_dir"]=> string(39) "C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL/certs" ["default_cert_dir_env"]=> string(12) "SSL_CERT_DIR" ["default_private_dir"]=> string(41) "C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL/private" ["default_default_cert_area"]=> string(33) "C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL" ["ini_cafile"]=> string(40) "C:/laragon/etc/ssl/ca-bundle.crt" ["ini_capath"]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: Hey, did you fix this?